# Fixing Broken Powerline Symbols?

Tags: release-hera, fonts

On my elementary OS 5.1.7 laptop, somehow the Powerline fonts are broken, whereas on my desktop, they are not. Here are pictures from my laptop of `tmux` and `nvim`:

[image]

[image]

I have reinstalled the `fonts-powerline` package and have made sure I have no overrides in `~/` or in `/etc/fonts`, but the symbols are broken as you can see. My elementary OS desktop, running the same version, does not have the same problem. I have also run `sudo fc-cache --verbose --really-force`, and no dice.

What can I try to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why I had to do this but I manually edited dconf to set the font. You can use the `dconf-editor` utility from that same package, or:

```
dconf write /io/elementary/terminal/settings/font '"Roboto Mono for Powerline 10"'
```

And yes, you need the strange double quoting, it uses GVariant format so it needs strings formatted like this.

My understanding was that `fonts-powerline` patched the fonts, but this works so I'm going to stop pursuing ghosts.